# How to access objects stored in a list

Tags: c++, list, object

How can i access objects stored in a list. I don't want to use vectors or `#include <list>`. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks! Here are my class definitions:

```
class UnsortedType  // UnsortedType.h   
{
    private:                
        int length, currentPos;
        book info[MAX_ITEMS];


    public:             
        UnsortedType();
        bool IsFull()  const ;
        int  LengthIs()  const ;  // returns length of list
        void RetrieveItem(book& item, bool& found);
        void InsertItem(book item); // adds objects to the list
        void DeleteItem(book item); // deletes objects in the list
        void ResetList(); // resets list to default length -1
        void GetNextItem(book& item); // gets the next object in the list

};
```

Stored in this list are book objects. contained in these objects are the title, author, price, etc... My question is how do I access each object once they are stored in the list. I want to be able to compare attributes of the objects stored in the list. For example the prices of each book.

```
//main
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
#include "textbook.h"
#include "Name.h"
#include "unsorted.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{


    book b1("The Exception to the Rulers", "Amy", "Goodman", "Hyperion", 342, "1-4013-0131", 21.95,'N');
    book b2("Who moved my cheese", "Spencer", "Johnson", "Red Tree", 95, "0-399-14446-3", 19.99,  'H');
    book b3("Hellbound Hearts", "Neil", "Gaiman", "Dark Harvest", 326, "978-1-4391-4090-1", 16.00, 'F');

    UnsortedType L1; // creating a list "L1" 

    L1.InsertItem(b1); // populating the list with the first book
    L1.InsertItem(b2); // populating the list with the second book
    L1.InsertItem(b3); // populating the list with the third book


    return 0;
}
```

These are the functions that are in book.h

```
// book.h
enum RelationType
{
    LESS, EQUAL, GREATER
};

class book
{
private: 
    string title; 
    Name aurthor; 
    string publisher; 
    string ISBN; 
    int pages; 
    float price; 
    char code; 


public:
    RelationType ComparedTo(book) const;
    class negativeNumber{};
    void setTitle(string);
    void setAurthor(string f, string l);
    void setPublisher(string);
    void setISBN(string);
    void setPages(int);
    void setPrice(float);
    void setCode(char);
    string getTitle();
    Name getAurthor();
    string getPublisher();
    string getISBN();
    int getPages();
    float getPrice();
    char getCode();
    void PrintBook();
    book(); //default constructor
    book(string, string, string, string, int, string, float, char); //constructor with args
    ~book(); //Destructor
};
```

Comment: Did you write `UnsortedType`?  Because it looks impossible to use.  There appears to be a function to get books out, but you can't specify which one.  DeleteItem apppears to need to search.  It makes extra copies of books left and right...  It looks like you can iterate over the list, but only once ever.

Comment: basically you have a wrapper around an array, so your question is 'how can i use an array of objects' - answer 'using normal array things'. For example you could add a GetItem(int idx) method to get an element from the array

Comment: If the idea is to get the list working, why are you using such a complicated `book` class?

Comment: WTB a reference (const or not, i'll take anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Book& UnsortedType::operator[](const int i))
{
  //check if array is in bounds
  return info[i];
}
```

this will allow you to access the book objects using the unsorted class L1[3];

or in your case, heres an example that accesses each object and determines the lowest price of the books:

```
double UnsortedType::FindLow()
{
    double low = 9999;      //used to store lowest value
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) //loop through array
    {
        if(info[i].price < low) //if the price of this book is lower than the current lowest
            low = info[i].price;
                //set low to new low
    }
    return low;
}
```

Comment: all the books are stored in L1. But when i try to do something like L1[i] to access the first element(first book) in the list(L1) I get an error. I need to know how to first access the objects in the list. Then I can start manipulating the data in the object.

Comment: you need to overload your [] operator or use a function, ill re-edit my post

Comment: THANKS that worked! im not sure i really understand why you had to overload the operator, but it works.